# Using time in a regression model with many observations per time point / interpreting Durbin-Watson in large sample

Tags: regression, time-series, large-data, durbin-watson-test

I am dealing with a huge dataset (>500k responses) containing measures of prejudice collected over a period of 10 years. We want to run a multiple regression model to test how various factors influence these responses - including time.

We could use a time series model, but as I understand it, that would require collapsing all measures per day into one - which would be unfortunate given very different numbers of responses and varying covariates. Is that true? Or is there an alternative?

As it stands, I would prefer using a regression model and have used the DW statistic to check whether auto-correlation is a problem. The value is 1.988 with rho estimated at .0059. Given the sample size, that is clearly statistically significant, but is it meaningful? Or can we conclude that such a small amount of correlation of residuals does not matter?